# Make Protocol conform to Equatable

Tags: swift

I have the following Input Field Rules

```
enum InputFieldRule: Equatable {
    case mandatory
    case lengthEquals(Int)
    case lengthBiggerThanOrEqual(Int)
    case lengthLessThanOrEqual(Int)
    case range(ClosedRange<Int>)
    case regex(TextValidationProtocol)
}
```

I can't make TextValidationProtocol `Equatable` because it's Protocol. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

TextValidationProtocol

```
protocol TextValidationProtocol {
    var regex: String { get }
}

enum ClientSideTextValidation: String, TextValidationProtocol {
    case notEmpty = "^.{1,}$"
    case password = "^.{6,}$"
    var regex: String { return rawValue }
}

struct ServerSideTextValidation: TextValidationProtocol {
    let regex: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `TextValidationProtocol` conform to `Equatable` too

```swift
extension TextValidationProtocol where Self: Equatable { }
```

Then implement `Equatable` required function inside the enum:

```swift
enum InputFieldRule: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: InputFieldRule, rhs: InputFieldRule) -> Bool {
        if case let .regex(lhsRegex) = lhs, case let .regex(rhsRegex) = rhs {
            return lhsRegex.regex == rhsRegex.regex
        }

        //TODO: Compare other enum cases if needed
    }

    ...
}
```

Example:

```swift
struct EmailRegex: TextValidationProtocol {
    var regex: String {
        return pattern
    }
    
    let pattern: String = "1234"
}

struct PhoneRegex: TextValidationProtocol {
    var regex: String {
        return pattern
    }
    
    let pattern: String = "1234"
}

let email = InputFieldRule.valid(EmailRegex())
let phone = InputFieldRule.valid(PhoneRegex())
print(email == phone)
```